# how can I convert a bytearray in to a float in python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion

I need to calcutale the decimal value of a 2 bytearray.
As input I get a bytearray (first part of the equation).
I parse this into 2 bytes (middle part of the equation).
I know what the results are (last part of the equation).

```
bytearray(b'\x11\xc7') = b'11c7' = 18.2

bytearray(b'\x07\x1b') = b'071b' = 18.19

bytearray(b'>Y') = b'3e59' = 2080

bytearray(b'>Z') = b'3e5a' = 2081.28
```

How can I calculate these values?

Comment: You're going to need to tell us what this 2-byte format is. (And if you don't know, you'll need to find out.) What does the documentation say?

Comment: FTR, it's not IEEE 754 binary16 format, with either endianness. And it doesn't look like any kind of sane fixed-point format either, given how different the byte sequences `\x11\xc7` and `\x07\x1b` are for such similar outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The 2-byte format is a 'DTP-9' format from KNX. The folowilg function does the work:

```
def calculate(raw):
    """Parse/deserialize from KNX/IP raw data. DTP-9"

    data = (raw[0] * 256) + raw[1]
    exponent = (data >> 11) & 0x0f
    significand = data & 0x7ff
    sign = data >> 15

    if sign == 1:
        significand = significand - 2048

    value = float(significand << exponent) / 100

    return value
```

( found info on xknx.io )

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @emence I used your answer for swift:

```
static func byteToFloat(_ raw:[UInt8])->Float{
    let data = (UInt32(raw[0]) * (256 as UInt32)) + UInt32(raw[1])
    let exponent = (data >> 11) & 0x0f
    var significand = UInt32(data) & (0x7ff as UInt32)
    let sign = data >> 15

    if sign == 1 {
        significand = significand - (2048 as UInt32)
    }
    
    let value = Float(significand << exponent) / 100

    return value
}
```